# Determining the right SEM value for one of feature based grammar rules

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, semantics

I'm writing up a semantic fcfg file of my own and I have this grammar rule:

```
NP -> DT NNP NNP NNP
```

I wanted to write this particular rule with semantic extenstion so something like this:

```
NP[NUM=?n,SEM = <?det(?nnp?nnp?nnp)>] -> DT[NUM=?n,SEM=?det] NNP[NUM=?n,SEM=?nnp] NNP[NUM=?n,SEM=?nnp] NNP[NUM=?n,SEM=?nnp]
```

I tried parsing this rule with this sentence:

```
The(det) Orlando(NNP) Magic(NNP) City(NNP)
```

It doesnt work?

Comment: Break down your grammar to the simplest form (NP -> DT NNP) and the add complexity (feature structure) one rule at a time.

Comment: @alvas can you please give an example?

Comment: Take a look at how a sort of complex grammar is broken down and debugged step-by-step https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195584/nltk-fcfg-grammer-parser-out-of-index/48218610#48218610 . Put some more effort into trying and update the questions how you had tried to debug first. Then we can help you better. I believe in you!

Comment: @alvas Thank you. Will try it out!

Comment: @QuentinHyatt I think the problem is DT: if your DT definition has no NUM feature, it wouldn't work.